# Sum of all permutations between two given permutations

Tags: computer-science, permutations

I was trying to find the `rank difference` between two permutations with repetitions and which **has only digits**. More over I need to find the sum of all the permutations between them. I figured out that the first part can be solved by extending the general `permutation ranking without repetitions`.

Now regarding the second issue, I can directly find each permutation and get the sum if the number of digits were small. But, the number of digits in the permutation can be at most `500`!!, making my solution non-feasible. Any insights on how to find the sum??